# Rails - Unexpected object return value Rational

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

One of the data layer scripts that handles type evaluation in my Rails application was exhibiting strange behavior and upon digging we found the issue was:

```
Rational(BigDecimal(1), 1).class
=> BigDecimal
```

I'm struggling to find anything on this and why a `Rational` constructor is returning a `BigDecimal`. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like an oversight to me. If you look at [the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_1/rational.c#L2558), you'll see a bunch of type checks that don't cover `BigDecimal` (possibly because `BigDecimal` isn't core Ruby but in the standard library instead). Then you end up calling [`f_div`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_1/rational.c#L2637) which is just `BigDecimal(1)/1` in this case. Not an explanation, so not an answer, just a quick review of what's going on behind the curtain.